# IIS 6 - URL REWRITE MODULE

Tags: url, iis-7, iis-6, url-rewriting

IIS 6 - URL REWRITE MODULE: Can any one suugest me an article where i can find steps to install and use this rewrite module. i tried and looks like it is not an easy installation

Answer (score 1):

A very popular one is [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/), and is even recommended by MSDN. You can read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/06/18/rewriting-urls-on-iis5-iis6-or-iis7-mod-rewrite-on-iis.aspx).

Comment: i have downloaded zip file from http://iirf.codeplex.com/releases/view/13940 - i dont see any exe or a dll..

Comment: You must not have downloaded the MSI. [Click here to see the documentation](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/frames.htm), then click the "Installing IIRF" link in the left menu.

Comment: ok i have installed and added isap filter to my default website, now how to get started with the redirection rules, i need to redirect based on the query string.

Comment: You'll want to add RewriteRules to your INI files. These will take the form of regular expressions. I'm sorry to keep linking to the documentation, but the creators can explain it better than I. [Learn more about configuring the INI files](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/8f5e8495-babc-4dfb-9da9-4e9101e8d029.htm). [Learn how to make Regular Expressions based on Query String](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/frames.htm).

Comment: thanks , so i shud add the appropriate regexes to the ini files and place them in C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\IIRF, and point this location to the isapi filters in IIS for the default website(my proj is in defsualt website)? is this the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can install by below URL:

http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00461/0/Installation-of-URL-Rewriting-module-IIRF-for-IIS6-IIS7.html

All steps are described very well