# Redirect all requests to a path in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-6

Is there a way in IIS 6.0 to redirect all requests to a specific path?

For example, any requests for /site/subfolder/ or any resource under it (real or not) to be redirected based on the fact that it satisfies this criterion:

```
http://site/subfolder/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You need a ISAPI URL rewriter module. There's a couple to choose from on IIS6;

[IIS 6 - URL REWRITE MODULE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717822/iis-6-url-rewrite-module)